# Problemas con asp.Net Web Form

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Buen día colegas, estoy empezando en asp. Net y tengo varios problemas, Visual Studio me quita o me pone cosas inesperadas que no tengo en mi diseño. espero me puedan ayudar gracias de antemano.

[image: Este es mi diseño]

[image: como pueden ver en la ejecucion no aparece ni el boton ni el label de mensaje]

[image: Diseño en visual studio]

[image: aqui esta en ejecucion]

Comment: Que es lo que decis que quita y pone? las dos pantallas parecen diseños normales

Comment: Mira el boton agregar y el lbl mensaje me lo quita en el primer form, y en el otro form me pone un espacio en blanco debajo del titulo

Comment: estas utilizando master page?